# How do I make this nutrition label display properly with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, import, label

I'm designing a site that is going to display a nutrition label on it with dynamically filled nutritional information. I found some free code for a nutrition label online: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/egHEK 
but for some reason my label does not come out like the one in the example.

This is how my label displays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbjec.jpg

This is how I want my label to display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pviEl.jpg

I'm missing some lines and some of the formatting isn't correct. I believe it has to do with the @import "compass/css3"; not working properly.

Does anyone know how I can get my label to display exactly like the one from codepen? Thanks.

```
<style>
@import "compass/css3";

.image {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
body {
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.performance-facts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
}
.performance-facts__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
}
.performance-facts__header {
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  padding: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
.performance-facts__table {
  width: 100%;
  thead tr {
    th, td {
      border: 0;
    }
  }
  th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.25rem 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  td {
    &:last-child {
      text-align: right;
    }
  }
  .blank-cell {
    width: 1rem;
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .thick-row {
    th, td {
      border-top-width: 5px;
    }
  }
}
.small-info {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.performance-facts__table--small {
  @extend .performance-facts__table;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  thead {
    tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    }
  }
  td {
    &:last-child {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  th, td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.performance-facts__table--grid {
  @extend .performance-facts__table;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  td {
    &:last-child {
      text-align: left;
      &::before {
        content: "•";
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0 0.25rem 0 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.thick-end {
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
.thin-end {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<html>
<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/NutritionFacts.gif" class="image">

<section class="performance-facts">
  <header class="performance-facts__header">
    <h1 class="performance-facts__title">Nutrition Facts</h1>
    <p>Serving Size 1/2 cup (about 82g)
    <p>Serving Per Container 8</p>
  </header>
  <table class="performance-facts__table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" class="small-info">
          Amount Per Serving
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Calories</b>
          200
        </th>
        <td>
          Calories from Fat
          130
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="thick-row">
        <td colspan="3" class="small-info">
          <b>% Daily Value*</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Total Fat</b>
          14g
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>22%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell">
        </td>
        <th>
          Saturated Fat
          9g
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>22%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell">
        </td>
        <th>
          Trans Fat
          0g
        </th>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Cholesterol</b>
          55mg
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>18%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Sodium</b>
          40mg
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>2%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Total Carbohydrate</b>
          17g
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>6%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell">
        </td>
        <th>
          Dietary Fiber
          1g
        </th>
        <td>
          <b>4%</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell">
        </td>
        <th>
          Sugars
          14g
        </th>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="thick-end">
        <th colspan="2">
          <b>Protein</b>
          3g
        </th>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table class="performance-facts__table--grid">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          Vitamin A
          10%
        </td>
        <td>
          Vitamin C
          0%
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="thin-end">
        <td colspan="2">
          Calcium
          10%
        </td>
        <td>
          Iron
          6%
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p class="small-info">* Percent Daily Values are based on a 2,000 calorie diet. Your daily values may be higher or lower depending on your calorie needs:</p>

  <table class="performance-facts__table--small small-info">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <th>Calories:</th>
        <th>2,000</th>
        <th>2,500</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Total Fat</th>
        <td>Less than</td>
        <td>65g</td>
        <td>80g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell"></td>
        <th>Saturated Fat</th>
        <td>Less than</td>
        <td>20g</td>
        <td>25g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Cholesterol</th>
        <td>Less than</td>
        <td>300mg</td>
        <td>300 mg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Sodium</th>
        <td>Less than</td>
        <td>2,400mg</td>
        <td>2,400mg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Total Carbohydrate</th>
        <td>300g</td>
        <td>375g</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="blank-cell"></td>
        <th colspan="2">Dietary Fiber</th>
        <td>25g</td>
        <td>30g</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p class="small-info">
    Calories per gram:
  </p>
  <p class="small-info text-center">
    Fat 9
    &bull;
    Carbohydrate 4
    &bull;
    Protein 4
  </p>
</section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are embedding scss stylesheet in the html, you can't directly insert an SCSS (Sassy CSS) file into your HTML. That's because SASS is a superset (or so-called preprocessor or extension) of CSS3's syntax, which is NOT supported by web browsers.

Go to your codepen (https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/egHEK), in the css section, there is a dropdown which gives option to compile scss to the css, (view compiled css). Click on that, you will get the final compiled css as below:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
.image {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

body {
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.performance-facts {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.performance-facts table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.performance-facts__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
}

.performance-facts__header {
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  padding: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.performance-facts__header p {
  margin: 0;
}

.performance-facts__table, .performance-facts__table--small, .performance-facts__table--grid {
  width: 100%;
}
.performance-facts__table thead tr th, .performance-facts__table--small thead tr th, .performance-facts__table--grid thead tr th,
.performance-facts__table thead tr td,
.performance-facts__table--small thead tr td,
.performance-facts__table--grid thead tr td {
  border: 0;
}
.performance-facts__table th, .performance-facts__table--small th, .performance-facts__table--grid th,
.performance-facts__table td,
.performance-facts__table--small td,
.performance-facts__table--grid td {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.performance-facts__table td:last-child, .performance-facts__table--small td:last-child, .performance-facts__table--grid td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.performance-facts__table .blank-cell, .performance-facts__table--small .blank-cell, .performance-facts__table--grid .blank-cell {
  width: 1rem;
  border-top: 0;
}
.performance-facts__table .thick-row th, .performance-facts__table--small .thick-row th, .performance-facts__table--grid .thick-row th,
.performance-facts__table .thick-row td,
.performance-facts__table--small .thick-row td,
.performance-facts__table--grid .thick-row td {
  border-top-width: 5px;
}

.small-info {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.performance-facts__table--small {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.performance-facts__table--small thead tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.performance-facts__table--small td:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.performance-facts__table--small th,
.performance-facts__table--small td {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.performance-facts__table--grid {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
}
.performance-facts__table--grid td:last-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.performance-facts__table--grid td:last-child::before {
  content: "•";
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0.25rem 0 0;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.thick-end {
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.thin-end {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Embed this css in your html, it should work. Kindly increase `.performance-facts` width to 300 from 280, so it will look nice.

Comment: Ah yes, got it now. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it.